# How measured content of Calcium Carbonate in eggshells change with the use of different acids?

Tags: acid-base, titration

I am investigating the calcium content of chicken eggshells. The only literature I can find on this consistently and solely depend on the use of HCl to conduct back titration. I conducted the experiment using Acetic, Ascorbic, Lactic, Oxalic and Hydrochloric acid and reached values of 66.8%, 37.8%, 58.3%, 95.5% and 56.5% respectively with a percentage uncertainty of 0.45% overall.

Since I have no literature to compare, I am not sure of my results (except HCl, which is acceptible when the difference in molarities is accounted). And I lack the theoretical background to explain why different acids could yield different values?

I would like to ask to provide theoretical background, or at least to direct me to it.

Comment: When downvoting, can you also state the reason please?

Comment: I down voted because this has almost no relation to science: it is essentially alchemy with eggshells. The results are poor, there is no reason stated for even picking the acids used, there were apparently no preliminary runs using carefully weighed samples of actual pure calcium carbonate (an extremely inexpensive substance), and so on. It is just a poorly conceived muddle.

Comment: I was actually curious about why HCl was always preferred in this experiment when it was demonstrated in one of our labs. I posted here as I was unable to find background information on this, but maybe it was not right to post without any strong methodology. Sorry for taking your time and thanks for your reply.

Comment: We use HCl because it is a strong monoprotic acid that is inexpensive, readily available in high purity and it is non-oxidizing. The other acids you used are weak acids, which can only add unnecessary complications.

Comment: Thank you very much, have a nice day!

Comment: I guess you did this experiment just as an academic exercise. All other acids are weak acids, and HCl is the strong acid. Surprisingly, only HCl should have provided correct results and oxalic acid should have the worst results. Since your HCl results are incorrect, and off by >50%, the results of others are somewhat dubious too.

Comment: Oxalic acid forms precipitates with Ca ions, so it should have the most incorrect results.